# Issues error: cannot lock ref when fetch data on server

Tags: git, git-refspec

I got an issue when fetch new commits merged to.

[image]

I know how to resolve the problem with prune locally.
But the problem is at server and I can not ssh to (just run CI/CD set up before).
How can I resolve the problem with my local repository and push it on the repo (without run any command line on server)
Thank you guys for reading.

I intended to delete the branch cause the conflict. But I don't have permission tho.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git fatal: cannot lock ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45141188/git-fatal-cannot-lock-ref) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56084425/git-fatal-error-on-pull-cannot-lock-ref-unable-to-resolve-reference-reference or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574209/git-pull-error-cannot-lock-ref-ref-remotes-origin-xxx-exists-cannot-crea